# How to use a helper

Tags: magento-1.7, helper

I am creating a module that allows a user to input details into a form and save their details to allow relevant information to be forwarded to them at specified times.

To retrieve the details from the form and add them to the database I followed a tutorial and produced this code

```
    public function saveAction()
{
    $title = $this->getRequest()->getPost('title');
    $f_name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('f_name');
    $l_name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('l_name');
    if ( isset($title) && ($title != '') && isset($f_name) && ($f_name != '') && isset($l_name) && ($l_name != '') ) {
        $contact = Mage::getModel('prefcentre/prefcentre');
        $contact->setData('title', $title);
        $contact->setData('f_name', $f_name);
        $contact->setData('l_name', $l_name);
        $contact->save();
        $this->_redirect('prefcentre/index/emailPreferences');
    } else {
        $this->_redirect('prefcentre/index/signUp');
    }
}
```

The tutorial says to put it into the controller in a saveAction, and that works fine. However from my very limited understanding it would go in to a helper and i'd call the helper from the controller

I placed the above code in my helper and called it from within the saveAction using the following

```
Mage::helper('module/helpername');//returned blank screen and did not save
```

I also tried

```
Mage::helper('module/helpername_function');//returned error
```

My config has

```
<helpers>
    <prefcentre>
        <class>Ps_Prefcentre_Helper</class>
    </prefcentre>
</helpers>
```

1 . Should this code go in a helper, if not where should it go?

2 . How do I call the helper(or the location the code need to go) to utilise the code?

Comment: look at here  http://magentocodes.blogspot.in/2015/12/how-to-use-helpers-in-magento.html

Answer (score 1):

> 1 . Should this code go in a helper, if not where should it go?

The actual code you posted imo is predestinated to be used within a controller action because it realizes a very specific process flow: Get user data for a specific case -> save if applicable -> redirect.

Secondly, a helper imo never should control route dispatching. It's a helper, not a controller.

I fail to see any use case where putting the method into a helper would give any advantages.

> 2 . How do I call the helper(or the location the code need to go) to
>   utilise the code?

Your definition uses `<prefcentre>` as alias, so if you did setup the helper the Magento standard way and using the file `app/code/local/Ps/Prefcentre/Helper/Data.php`, than your helper methods are callable like this:

```
Mage::helper('prefcentre')->myMethodName();
```

Comment: Thankyou for that explanation. My reason for thinking a helper was need was due to me reading that magento uses skinny controllers and a helper is there to take some of the load of a controller (or maybe i've got it mixed up by the sound of it)